# Adding text to a image using PIL

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-imaging-library

So, I want the bot to send a welcome card with the user's profile picture & text saying " Welcome {user.name} ", but the text part isn't working. I have got no error in the console.

Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageFont, ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    wc = Image.open("wc.jpg")

    asset = member.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.open(data)

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(wc)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("Littlecandy.ttf", 24)
    
    pfp = pfp.resize((474,382))
    draw.text((549,284), f"{member.display_name}", (171, 5, 171), font=font)
    wc.paste(pfp, (727,209))
    wc.save("wcm.jpg")

    await client.get_channel(850634788633182218).send(file = discord.File('wcm.jpg'))
```

Comment: please share the error you got

Comment: ah! I have stated it first i have got no error in the console.

Comment: Actually o forgot to add NO before error in the line " I have got error in the console " . It's mistake i really sorry.

Comment: Ah i see, is the image sending just without the text, or is it not working at all?

Comment: Yeah you are right the bot is sending only the welcome card with the users Profile Pic. Not the text.

Comment: You resize the image to (474,382) then write your text to (549,284), which is well off the right edge of the image.  Be careful with your coordinates.

Comment: @TimRoberts ah! i actually tested it by removing the picture part, i used only text it still didn't work, any more suggestions ?

Comment: _removing the picture part_ -- How did you do the text without the picture/  You'd still need to create the image large enough to hold the text.

Answer (score 0):

So, i have not got the answer but when i removed the RGB code that is this `(171, 5, 171)` than i tested it & it worked.

Here's my changed code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageFont, ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO

@client.comamnd()
async def on_member_join(member):

    wc2 = Image.open("wc2.jpg")

    asset = member.avatar_url_as(size=64)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.open(data)

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(wc2)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("BalsamiqSans-BoldItalic.ttf", 45)
    text = f"{member}" 

    pfp = pfp.resize((211,181))
    wc2.paste(pfp, (30,28))
    draw.text((26,235),text,font=font,fill='orange')
    wc2.save("wcm.jpg")

    await client.get_channel(850634788633182218).send(file = discord.File('wcm.jpg'))
```